# How to add custom data into laravel-passport's JWT payload?

Tags: laravel, jwt, laravel-passport, payload

Is there a way to add custom data into the payload in Laravel/Passport?

When im using tymondesigns/jwt-auth, You usually just add this in the model:

```
    public function getJWTCustomClaims()
    {
        return [
            'id'              => $this->id,
            'name'            => $this->name,
            'role'            => $this->role,
        ];
    }
```

But how do you customize it when using Lavel-passport? I just want the id, name, and role to be included in the payload. Just like the image/link below(last 3 items on the payload):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3qd2h.jpg